# Inline clearfix before <strong> in css

Tags: html, tinymce, css, clearfix

I would like to break the line automatically before a `<strong>` tag begins. I'd try a couple of things, but can't find out how to do so.

I tried:

```
strong, b {font-weight: bolder;clear:both;display:block;}
```

and

```
strong:before, b:before {clear:both;display:block;height:1%}
strong, b {font-weight: bolder;}
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: You can't apply clear to inline elements, it will automatically revert to "inline".

Comment: `display: block;` is not inline. The problem is that the content is null (different than empty) within the block so it just won't even display the `:before` elements. Adding `content: ""` is all he needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
strong:before {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    zoom: 1.0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dxQBy/8/

I learned about this a few weeks ago after running across [A new micro clearfix hack - Nicholas Gallagher](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)

Answer (score 0):

are you not looking for something like this?

```
strong, b { 
    font-weight: bold;
    display:block;
    clear: both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/seany789/dxQBy/4/

Comment: Yours will clear before & after, instead of just before. http://jsfiddle.net/dxQBy/9/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/dxQBy/8/